# Change Rotations and Distributions of Y-Ticks on Matplotlib Radar Chart

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, radar-chart

So I am making some radar charts for an academic paper. As can be seen all the yticks cluster in the northeast corner, is there any way in which it would be possible to move these ticks to make the graph more readable. What i am looking for in short is:

1)A way to rotate individual yticks say by 45 degrees

2)A way to shift the position of a ytick in terms of position on the circle, so say move 0.03 to north, 0.1 to south and 3.16 to southwest.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import pickle
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 20

plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman'] + plt.rcParams['font.serif']


sample = [
    35.417256011315416,
    0.028288543140028287,
    1.3578500707213579,
    3.3663366336633667,
    0.8203677510608205,
    35.445544554455445,
    3.3946251768033946,
    19.46251768033946,
    0.7072135785007072,
]


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
np.seterr(divide = 'warn') 

sample = samplelistapt

get_mag = lambda x: 10**min(np.floor(np.log10(x)))
init_mag = get_mag(sample)
sample = np.array(sample) / get_mag(sample)
N = len(sample)

theta = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi / N)

listofsamples = np.log10(sample)

actuallistofsamples = listofsamples.tolist()
print(actuallistofsamples)

bars = ax.bar(theta, actuallistofsamples, width=0.4, color = '#003F5C')
ax.set_xticks(theta)
#ax.set_xticklabels(range(1, len(theta) + 1))
ax.set_xticklabels(['           Delayed\n           Execution', '            File\n            Opening', 'Firewall\nModification', 'Permission              \nModification              ', 'Persistence                 ', 'Proxied          \nExecution           ', 'Reconnaissance          ', '    Registry\n    Modification', '    Task\n    Stopping'], visible=False)
#ax.set_xticklabels(['           Delayed\n           Execution', '            File\n            Opening', 'Firewall\nModification', 'Permission              \nModification              ', 'Persistence                 ', 'Proxied          \nExecution           ', 'Reconnaissance          ', '    Registry\n    Modification', '    Task\n    Stopping'])

dat = np.log10(sample)
print(dat)
#exit()
ax.set_ylim(0,max(dat))
ax.xaxis.grid(False)

ax.yaxis.grid(True)
precision = 2  # Change to your desired decimal precision
plt.xticks(fontsize=20,rotation=45)
#plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
plt.yticks(rotation=90)

ax.set_yticklabels([str(round((10 ** x) * init_mag, precision)) for x in ax.get_yticks()])

   plt.show()
```

Graphs in paper:

[image: Graphs in paper]
Output of code:

[image: One singular graph, output of this code]